# Flutter application to print reciept on thermal printer using bluetooth_print package is not working in background. How to do that?

Tags: android, flutter, bluetooth, background, thermal-printer

Using the following package (bluetooth_print: ^4.3.0) we have developed a flutter android mobile application for restaurant owner. It will print a order receipt whenever a new order is placed and notification is received from firebase.

It is working fine in foreground when the screen is on. But it is throwing an error while in background(after pressing home button). I guess it is facing an issue while accessing native code. This is the error message:

```
No implementation found for method "startScan" on channel "bluetooth_print/methods"
```

We tried to run this code as background service using many packages like flutter_background_service & background_fetch. But nothing seem to be working.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Here is the github link to the code: https://github.com/aTech0808/print_order_withfcm